# To convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to IEnumerable<DataRow>

Tags: c#, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

My Code:

I converted datatable to dynamic rows using IEnumerable`<dynamic>`

```
var dynamicRows = DataTableX.AsDynamicEnumerable(dt);
var rows = dynamicRows.AsQueryable().ToGridModel(1, 0, orderBy, string.Empty, filter).Data;
```

Now I need to create Excel of these rows. SO I used the following code which is of type IEnumerable`<DataRow>`

```
var output = CreateXlsStream(rows);
```

Now I can't able to assign the rows since it is of type IEnumerable`<DataRow>` and source is of type IEnumerable`<dynamic>`. I don't know how to convert from IEnumerable`<dynamic>` to IEnumerable`<DataRow>`

Comment: @L.B, I used Data.Cast<DataRow>() but in the CreateXlsStream function, the error message is displaying as "Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'"

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to explicitely assign properties from one instance to another.
This can be done by `foreach` loop on initial Collection.

Advantages are total control of assigned fields and their values.